# Where to report pornographic questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, offensive, inappropriate-content

Stack Overflow is for serious programmers. If I find a user discussing female anatomy and other carnal stuff, where and how can I report such these discussions? Does Stack Exchange have a dedicated site (like it has for math) where discussions on sexual matters could go and leave Stack Overflow for programmers only?

Comment: A link to an example would be nice (for evaluation purposes only, of course).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Heh, I was writing exactly the same comment ;)

Comment: I hope this isn't about the "Boobs Operator".... because that is a serious programming thing.

Comment: Well at least we can talk about male anatomy and not offend anyone

Comment: @Yannis. I don't think there was any need, while you were editing the question, to Americanise the spelling of *maths*.

Comment: @TRiG It was the capitalization that bothered me and went with the quick fix (Chrome's spelling thingy). Which I've now set back to _proper_ English, thanks for reminding me ;P

Comment: Sorry folks, but I think this user was trolling us: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646543/does-too-much-programming-lead-to-reduced-libido

Answer (score 12):

Just use the "flag" button, beneath the question.

After the box pop up, I would choose "it is not welcome in our community" because they are offensive, at least for me.

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

[Once you get 15 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts), you can flag posts that appear to be unrelated to the question or noise.

Until you have enough reputation, you should just let more experienced users handle the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Does it have anything to do with programming? If not, just flag/vote to close as off topic. It's it's spam, flag it as such.

Questions about human anatomy can go [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/). There used to be a beta site on [Sexuality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality), but it was closed. However, there is another proposal for such a site [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40921/human-sexuality?referrer=q4NWN5C_MtAnXLaDPCj7kA2), you can follow it if you're interested.